# problems with a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I will start saying with I'm really a noob on PHP and I need to solve a problem, I know the logic, however in the syntaxis I'm dead.

Here is the case.

I need to create a wordpress loop, which will display images with a span class with 3 different colors, 1 per loop, so it goes, 0 = green, 1 = blue, 2 = pink.

Since I have 3 colors a X numbers of outputs, I think about creating an array from 0 to 2, an assign a value according the colors I described, then create a conditional that will go as, if i > 2, then i = 0.

With this I will just echo the array value on my span class, that should do the trick.

What I need help with is creating the syntaxys for this, so far, this is what I have:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $i = 0 ?>
 <?php 
    $array = array(
      0 => 'green', 
      1 => 'blue', 
      2 => 'pink',
    ); 
  ?>
 <span class="<?php echo $array ?>;">Title</span>

 <?php
  $i++;
 ?>
 <?if ($i > 2) { $i=0; } endif; ?> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I'm missing the part where I should compare the counter i with the array.

I would appreciated any help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few **problems** with this code (as well as some suggestions).

- You were defining `$i = 0;` inside the while loop meaning it was always `== 0`
- You are trying to print the `$array` instead of one item

How to **fix**:

- Move `$i = 0;` outside the while loop (so it's defined before the loop)
- Use `echo $array[$i]` to echo the item id you're looking for
- Use the modulo operator to get the remainder of `$i / 3` and use that as your index

You could also

- Define the array on one line `$colors = array('green', 'blue', 'pink');` which will behave the same - this works as PHP uses a default index starting at 0
- Use variables like `$colors` instead of `$array` to make it clearer what's going on
- Reduce the amount of `<?php` tags to keep things clearer
- Define the array (now called `$colors`) outside of the loop

See the complete code below

```
<?php 
  $colors = array(
    0 => 'green', 
    1 => 'blue', 
    2 => 'pink',
  ); 

  $i = 0;
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();    
?>
<span class="<?php echo $colors[$i % 3] ?>;">Title</span>
<?php
  $i++;
  endwhile;
?>
```

And a further simplification

```
<?php 
  $colors = array('green', 'blue',  'pink'); 
  $i = 0;
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();    
?>
    <span class="<?php echo $colors[$i % 3] ?>;">Title</span>
<?php
    $i++;
  endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: wow! this made the trick perfectly, thanks a ton for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you are redeclaring `$array` every time you run the loop. Put that before you start the `while` loop.

Secondly, you need to access the element inside the array, by using an index:

```
<span class="<?php echo $array[$i] ?>;">Title</span>
```

Thirdly, you need to put the `$i = 0` *before* the `while` loop. What's happening here is the `$i` variable is being reset to `0` every time.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing whole `$array` instead of single array element (which is `$array[$i]`),  you're also resetting your counter (`$i = 0`) inside your `while` loop:

```
<?php 
    // a little bit cleaned up version of your code
    $array = array(
        0 => 'green', 
        1 => 'blue', 
        2 => 'pink',
    ); 

   $i = 0;
   while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
   <span class="<?php echo $array[$i] ?>;">Title</span>
<?php
    $i++;
    if ($i > 2) { $i=0; }

    endwhile; 
?>
```